# Loop through a Map's key-value pairs

Tags: elixir

How to iterate over a map's key-value pairs in Elixir?

This doesn't work:

```
my_map = %{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}

Enum.each my_map, fn %{k => v} ->
    IO.puts "#{k} --> #{v}"
end
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Turns out you iterate over a `Map` exactly like you do over a `Keyword List` (i.e. you use a `tuple`):

```elixir
Enum.each(%{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, fn {k, v} ->
  IO.puts("#{k} --> #{v}")
end)
```

[Comprehensions](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/comprehensions.html) also work:

```elixir
for {k, v} <- %{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3} do
  IO.puts("#{k} --> #{v}")
end
```

---

***Note:** If you use [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2) and return a tuple, you'll end up with a Keyword List instead of Map. To convert it into a map, use [`Enum.into/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#into/2) or [`Map.new/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#new/2).*